# gnome-terminal: strange control characters on Alt key

Tags: keyboard, gnome-terminal, control-characters

<strike>I probably misconfigured something, but I don't know what.</strike> (see UPDATE 1 and 2 below) In `gnome-terminal`, when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> (without any other key), it immediately sends `^[<` to the terminal (I tested by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> before <kbd>Alt</kbd>). Since I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> a lot, this is very unfortunate, because the control sequence will, for example, move to the beginning of history or do strange stuff in `vim`. 
The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, however,
does still work and cycles through the windows as wanted.

What might be the reason and how can I restore the default behavior in gnome-terminal?

- OS: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia x86_64
- Kernel: 5.3.0-24-generic
- Shell: bash 4.4.20
- GNOME Terminal 3.28.1 using VTE 0.52.2 +GNUTLS -PCRE2

**UPDATE 1**

I found out that this happens only on the laptops keyboard itself, but not using an external attached usb keyboard. While the external keyboard is attached both <kbd>Alt</kbd>-keys behave differently.

The laptop is a Lenovo P53.

I still don't know how to fix it for the laptops keyboard but at least I am closer to the origins of the issue.

**UPDATE 2**
Running `xev` I shortly hit (pressed and immediately released) <kbd>Alt</kbd> a single time; first on the laptops keyboard and then on the external USB keyboard:

```
# LAPTOP KEYBOARD ALT-KEY

MappingNotify event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x2b6, subw 0x0, time 9398319, (162,-8), root:(903,449),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x2b6, subw 0x0, time 9398319, (162,-8), root:(903,449),
    state 0x18, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x2b6, subw 0x0, time 9398360, (162,-8), root:(903,449),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x2b6, subw 0x0, time 9398360, (162,-8), root:(903,449),
    state 0x10, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

# EXTERNAL USB KEYBOARD ALT-KEY

MappingNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    request MappingKeyboard, first_keycode 8, count 248

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x2b6, subw 0x0, time 9402608, (162,-8), root:(903,449),
    state 0x10, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x6a00001,
    root 0x2b6, subw 0x0, time 9402704, (162,-8), root:(903,449),
    state 0x18, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

**UPDATE 3**

It's probably a hardware defect (see comments and answer). I will get a new keyboard from the manufacturer.

Comment: it would help if you tried to run `xev` and see what happens exactly when you press Alt on the laptop's keyboard (both mouse and keyboard events)

Comment: @mosvy: thanks, I added the output to the question as UPDATE 2

Comment: looks like depressing the `Alt` key (64) really also pulls the `<` key (94) after it. FWIW, this is not a gnome-terminal, xkb or terminfo/curses problem. Try switching to a virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F3, etc) or running a root shell and check (with `showkey`) if pressing the Alt key also generates another unrelated keycode event.

Comment: Same behavior in virtual terminal (ctrl-alt-f3) and in `sudo sh`

Comment: Since I have a dual boot, I also tested in windows 10 and it's also the same behavior. A friend of mine thinks it could be a short circuit in the keyboard hardware.

Comment: @mosvy you should post an answer summarizing this (for the bounty)

Comment: I had a call with the tech support of the manufacturer and they also think its a hardware defect because the external one is fine - fortunately it's in warranty-time and I will get a new keyboard and see if this works.

Comment: @intika I'm really not sure if this is not a driver or firmware glitch instead -- maybe there's someone with similar or identical hardware out there who can confirm. I would suggest the OP to change the title to include the laptop model.

Comment: @mosvy such bug on the drivers should be fixed on the windows version... i don't think it's the case ;) (not impossible but very rare) what's most evident is a hardware issue as the op suggested... OR

Comment: or @Stuck i already have a similar case when the keyboard wire is not well connected to the motherboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a hardware defect and was confirmed by the manufacturer. Replacing the keyboard solved the issue. Thanks for helping to investigate!